# What is this method returning?

Tags: java, parameters, int, return

What does the "(int)" actually do in the following return statement?

```
public double calc(double amount){
    return (int)(amount * 100)/100;
}
```

I was expecting that this method would return the same value that was passed in since I'm multiplying by 100 and then dividing by 100 . . . bringing me back to the original value yet when I tested in the compiler that was false. For Instance:

```
    carInformation myCar = new carInformation("");
    System.out.println(myCar.calc(34.86432456789));
```

I get:

```
34.0
```

why is this so?

Comment: It floors the value. Check out primitive narrowing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what does that mean?

Comment: It's a *really* convoluted way to write `Math.floor(...)`.

Comment: It chops off the digits after two decimal places. Or it would if it were written correctly. It should be `(int)(amount * 100) / 100.0;`

Comment: @IanMcLaird if its like Math.Floor() then wouldn't it be 35 instead of 34 since it would round 34.8 to 35. . . I just saw that in an example

Comment: No, `Math.floor()` always rounds down. Like the floor of the room you are in, it is always down. `Math.ceil()` always rounds up. You're thinking of `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 1):

After the multiplication, the cast to `int` truncates anything beyond the decimal point, so
`3486.432456789` becomes `3486`, which is divided by 100 to get `34`.  It's overkill; no multiplication or division was necessary, just: `(int) amount`.  Then the return value is a `double`, so it gets implicitly converted back to a `double`: `34.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is cast to an `int`, it will truncate the value `34.86...` to `34`. Integers don't store decimal places, so it just chops off anything to the right of the decimal point.

But since you return a `double`, your method converts your value and adds the extra decimal place: `34.0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). A conversion is done as described

> In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a
>   long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int,
>   as follows:
>
> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the
>   floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward
>   zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are
>   two cases:
>
> If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long,
>   then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>
> Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then
>   the result of the first step is the int value V.

So the value of

```
(amount * 100)
```

which is of type `double`, is converted to an `int` because of the cast. It is then divided  by `100`. Because your method is declared as returning a `double`, that result is [widened](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) from `int` to `double` with the following rule:

> [...] the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded
>   version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode

Answer (score 0):

- The `(int)` casts the numerator to an int. So, you will have 3486.
- The `/100` performs an *integer division*. You will have 34.

To achieve what you want, perform a floating-point division:

```
return (int)(amount * 100.0) / 100.0;
```